# Determinant: signed area of parallelogram question from Wiki

Tags: linear-algebra

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) defines the determinant as follows and my question is if this definition is correct:

Signed Area = $|u||v| sin \theta = |u^\Gamma||v| cos \theta' = \begin{bmatrix} -b \\ a \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} c \\ d \end{bmatrix} = ad - bc$, where $u = (a, b)$ and $u^\Gamma = (-b, a)$ is of the complementary angle to a perpendicular vector.

Is this definition true?  I use an example vector and the result differs in sign for the $sin$ equation between $-1$ and $1$.  For instance:

$u = (0, 1), v = (1, 0), u^\Gamma = (-1, 0)$

$|u||v| sin \theta = 1*1*sin(\frac \pi 2) = 1$

$|u^\Gamma||v| cos \theta' = |-1| * |1| cos(\pi) = -1$

$\begin{bmatrix} -b \\ a \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} c \\ d \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = -1*1 + 0*0 = -1$

$ad - bc = 0*0 - 1*1 = -1$

Comment: When you use the formula $|u| |v| \sin \theta$, you need to use $-\pi/2$. The angle is negative, because going from $u$ to $v$ is clockwise. This gives $-1$ instead of $1$, and it agrees with with the other calculation.

Comment: It depends on how $\theta$ is defined.  It should be the *orientated angle* between $u$ and $v$: it's the angle by which $u$ must be turned anti-clockwise to be parallel to $v$.  Hence the orientated angle between $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ is $3\pi/2$; the orientated angle between $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ is $\pi/2$.